# How to know the biggest memory users processes

Tags: windows, performance, memory, web, windows-server-2008

We are hosting our website in a dedicated server,to take a look at how performances are,i found by using Process Explorer that the Physical Memory used is 7,6GB

I'm worried because we have 8GB of RAM and if the number of users Goes up,this may lead to problems:slow website and that will be borying.

How can i know what is the biggest users processes of Memory.is it possible to know that using Process Explorer or Performance Monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   Using Process Explorer, merely click on the heading in the processes list for "Virtual Memory" or "Working Set" (also known as Physical Memory).  This will sort the usage numerically from highest to smallest (and clicking again will sort the reverse).

The first time you use Process Explorer, you may need to customize its display of values.  Right-click on the headers, and choose "Select Columns...". Select [Process Memory] tab, and choose [X] Virtual Size.

Comment: thanks.in the process list i see just:PID,CPU,Private Bytes,Working Set,Description,CompanyName.I don't see Physical Memory colmun,neither Virtual Memory.I see them just when i click system info,but with no list of process.How can i add those columns

Comment: Google is your friend, as is the help for the program.  "Working Set" is physical memory occupied.  Right-click on the headers, and choose "Select Columns...".  Select [Process Memory] tab, and choose [X] Virtual Size.